# How to use angular material circular progress bar

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to use a progress bar when I am uploading a video, but the progress bar appears on load page and sty forever.

```
<div ng-show="!$ctrl.setNewVideoRecord()">
    <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" md-diameter="100">
    </md-progress-circular>
</div>

<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="$ctrl.setNewVideoRecord()"> Add video</md-button>

self.setNewVideoRecord = function () {
adminService.setNewVideoRecord(self.fileForUpload)
    .then(function () {
});
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to apply a scope variable. and set the value of that scope variable accordingly inside the function. Right now you are calling a function to apply ng-show but that function should return either true or false based on which you will show progress bar . The best way is :

```
<div ng-show="$ctrl.videoUploading">
  <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" md-diameter="100">
  </md-progress-circular>
</div>


<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="$ctrl.setNewVideoRecord()"> Add video</md-button>

self.videoUploading = false;
self.setNewVideoRecord = function () {
  self.videoUploading = true;
  adminService.setNewVideoRecord(self.fileForUpload)
   .then(function () {
    // your code here, and when the video uploading is completed again set the variable false
      self.videoUploading = false;
 });
};
```